# Meaning of "picture" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The child's practised eye instantly noted his father's state. He dived
>   under the table, where experience had taught him was a rather safe
>   place. The dog, lacking skill in such matters, was, of course, unaware
>   of the true condition of affairs. He looked with interested eyes at
>   his friend's sudden dive. He interpreted it to mean: Joyous gambol. He
>   started to patter across the floor to join him. He was **the picture
>   of** a little dark-brown dog en route to a friend.

It's from 'A dark brown dog' by Stephen Crane in 1893.

What does the picture mean exactly?

It sounds a bit odd for me to just interpret it 'image or figure' in the flow of sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, a portrait (painting of a person) was referred to a likeness, and the phrase "has a likeness to" is used to mean "bears a resemblance to".

Similarly, in the phrase "He was the picture of a ... dog", the 'picture' is meant to state that the dog bore resemblance to a stereotypical dog that is happy to meet a friend.

In this context, **"picture" doesn't mean only the visual appearance, it also means the behaviour** (i.e. joyous gambolling, pattering of the feet).

Answer (score 1):

> He was the picture of ...

means in this context

> He looked just like ...